# Navigation link area in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm working on a photo gallery site using fancybox. The way it's working now, to navigate next/previous, the link area is tied to the position of the arrows. You can click anywhere from about the center of each image to the y axis of the arrow image. If I move the arrows out and away from the image, the clickable area widens with it. I do this in the css file. What my client wants (for some reason) is to be able to click right/left up to the edge of the browser window without the arrows being way out from the photo.

How can I do that? Below is the section of the css file that controls the position of the arrow images (which are in base64 format):

```
a.fancybox-prev {
left: 0px;
}

a.fancybox-next {
right: 0px;
}
```

Above moves the arrows in or away from the photo.

```
a.fancybox-nav span {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: 46px;
height: 46px;
margin-top: -23px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 8040;
}
```

The above has to do with the sprite and vertical positioning.

```
a.fancybox-prev span {
left: 0;
background-position: 0 -50px;
}

a.fancybox-next span {
right: 0;
background-position: 0 -100px;
}
```

The above also changes the arrows, close button and enlarge icons.

I've tried all combinations, been at it for hours now. Any ideas on how to make the whole left half of the browser window a 'previous' link and the same for the right side of the window?

Kirk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a weird request indeed but I would do,

first, disabling closing fancybox when clicking the overlay (outside the fancybox), and

second, bind a `click` to the fancybox's *overlay* and check if the visitor clicked left or right the content, then call the `$.fancybox.prev()` or `$.fancybox.next()` methods accordingly like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    margin: [20, 60, 20, 60], // Increase left/right margin for arrows position
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            closeClick: false // prevents closing when clicking overlay (outside fancybox)
        }
    },
    afterShow: function () {
        var offset = $(".fancybox-inner").offset(),
            offset_Right = offset.left + $(".fancybox-inner").width();
        $(".fancybox-overlay").css("cursor", "pointer").on("click", function (e) {
            if ( e.pageX < offset.left ) {
                $.fancybox.prev();
            } else if ( e.pageX > offset_Right ) {
                $.fancybox.next();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Then you could use some css to place the arrows where you want them.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8WM6r/show/)**

Comment: Wow ... almost. You've got it to be clickable right to the edge but something is wrong when the cursor is over the photo. It works only sometimes. On the landscape photos, it works when you don't move the mouse ... once you move the cursor to a different part of the photo, it stops working. The portrait photos don't seem to work at all.

Good stuff though, how cool.

Comment: @KirkSL over the photos you would need to use the arrows, this workaround only covers the areas beside the image, not inside of it.

Comment: Legendary answer. @Kirk SL you need to accept this answer.